# Convert Excel spreadsheet formulas to values from command line

Tags: python, excel, automation

I wish to programmatically interact with spreadsheets from python/openpyxl.
However, I do not want to deal with formulae in openpyxl; in fact, I seek a "frozen" formula-to-value approach.  This includes preserving type fidelity, meaning numerics are distinct from strings (and by formatting convention, I can distinguish numerics from dates).  So my goal is some sort of script/program, **in any language**, where I can do this:

```
$ force2value --input original.xlsx --output frozen.xlsx
```

The net effect is exactly as if I had opened `original.xlsx` in Excel and done the whole select cells, copy, and repaste special as values only, for each sheet, followed by Save As.  If the approach is some sort of wild macro-ish thing that can be "fed" from the command line, that's OK too.

Answer (score 0):

**in any language**?  How about VBA:

```
Cells.Copy
Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\path\filename.xlsm"
```

Comment: Certainly an elegant and simple approach -- but how do I make that happen from the command line?   Also: original.xlsx cannot be assumed to contain this VBA.